# Is $h(\mathbf{a},b)=\int_\Omega f(\mathbf{x})e^{-g(\mathbf{x})}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}$ differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f\colon\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ be an affine function and $g\colon\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ be a non-negative function. We define $h\colon\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ as follows
$$
h(\mathbf{a},b)=\int_\Omega f(\mathbf{x})e^{-g(\mathbf{x})}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x},
$$
where $\Omega=\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n\colon\mathbf{a}^\top\mathbf{x}+b\geq0\}$ is the "positive" halfspace defined by the hyperplane $\mathbf{a}^\top\mathbf{x}+b=0$, where $\mathbf{a}\in\Bbb{R}$, $b\in\Bbb{R}$ are arbitrary.

Can we state that $h$ is differentiable in $\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}$? How could we prove that?

**EDITS:**

1. I have evaluated the above integral with specific choices of $f$, $g$ and the resulting function $h$ *seems to be* differentiable (as a sum of differentiable functions). However, I would like to show differentiability in the more abstract form given above.
2. I have shown that $h$ is convex over $\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{R}$, but I think this requires to prove differentiability first.

Comment: Start by changing variables to $\mathbf{y} \geq 0$.

Comment: And then what? I mean, is there a generic mechanism for proving differentiability in integrals?

Comment: Dominated convergence is the usual approach.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @Ian, but I still can't see how I could use it in this case...

Comment: Well, write what you get after you change variables.

Comment: @Ian, I have evaluated the above integral for specific functions $f$, $g$ and the result seems to be differentiable (as a sum of two differentiable quantities), but I wonder if there is a way to show the differentiability of $h$ before the integration.

Comment: I understand. The point of my suggestion is to make it so that the integrand, rather than the domain of integration, depends on $\mathbf{a}$ and $b$. This makes it so you can use the "usual machinery" to differentiate under the integral sign.

Comment: I see... But I need to put some thought on your advice, I'm not sure whether this is possible without being very specific with my functions. I'm looking for a more abstract way of proving its differentiability, or for some sufficient conditions, where I could plug my functions in, in order to show what I want. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: The variable change has nothing to do with $f$ and $g$, it only depends on how you chose the domain.